# using radio buttones as check box

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, forms

I am learning how to develop WordPress plugins from [this tutorial series](http://www.devlounge.net/extras/how-to-write-a-wordpress-plugin) and now I am on [this tutorial](http://www.devlounge.net/code/constructing-an-wordpress-plugin-admin-panel) , but I found a strange thing: there is used two RadioButtones to get values "True" or "False" where they could use one CheckBox

```
<label for="devloungeHeader_yes">
    <input type="radio" id="devloungeHeader_yes" name="devloungeHeader" value="true" <?php if ($devOptions['show_header'] == "true") { _e('checked="checked"', "DevloungePluginSeries"); }?> />
    Yes
</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<label for="devloungeHeader_no">
    <input type="radio" id="devloungeHeader_no" name="devloungeHeader" value="false" <?php if ($devOptions['show_header'] == "false") { _e('checked="checked"', "DevloungePluginSeries"); }?>/>
    No
</label>
```

I saw something similar on joomla admin page, where there was used 2 radio buttons to get the same result.

**So, is there any (html, css, javascript, php, just any) advantage of using two radio buttons instead of one checkbox?**

Comment: for 2 values nope. radio buttons are pretty much XOR'ing all awailable options - for two a checkbox does the same ;-). But Radiobuttons can have a initial value (none), checkboxes are either preset true/false. Maybe that can be a reason

Comment: @Najzero No, that can't be reason because on that tutorial it is required to have result "True" or "False", by default the result is "True", so I thing there is just bad coding practice on that tutorial.

Comment: The tutorial is 5yrs old, and outdated in many ways.

Comment: IMHO it's all about user experience and not seeking to make your markup/code more succinct and/or efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found out why using two radio buttons with same names and different values "True" and "False" is better than checkboxes. when a checkbox is NOT checked, it will not be submitted to the server. But when you use radio buttons with "True" and "False" values those radio buttons will be submitted on the server, so php will get result from html form anyway. So with ckeckbox you have only two options:

```
1) when chebox is checked and is submited (value == "checked")
2) when checkbox is Not checked and it is not submited
```

with php you have those two options:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['testCheckBox'])) {
    // it is submited so it means it is Checked!
} else {
    // it is not submited because it is not checked or there is something wrong!
}
?>
```

But with radio buttons you have three options:

```
1) when radio "True" is checked and is submited
2) when radio "False" is checked and is submited
3) when radio is not SUBMITED, so something is not working properly
```

php example:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['testRadioButton'])) { // testRadioButton is submited!
    if($_POST['testRadioButton'] == "true"){
        // True is checked, do something
    } elseif(($_POST['testRadioButton'] == "false"){
        // False is checked, do something
    }
} else {
    // it not Submited! so there is definitely something wrong with code
}
?>
```